# Hibernate Criteria: Eagerly load ManyToMany collection

Tags: hibernate, criteria, fetch

My problem seems pretty straightforward to me, but I just can't seem to find an answer that works. I have a Hibernate Entity which has a ManyToMany association with another Entity, which is fetched lazily by default. I want to create a Criteria which will return the Entity with the ManyToMany association loaded eagerly.

Here is the Entity in question (with irrelevant parts removed):

```
@Entity
public class Order {

  @ManyToMany
  private List<Item> items;

  @ManyToMany
  private List<Discount> discountEntries;

  ...

}
```

Here are my notable attempts thus far and the results:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Order.class)
                                .setFetchMode("items", FetchMode.SELECT)
                                .setFetchMode("discountEntries", FetchMode.SELECT);
criteria.list();
```

- Loads the items lazily

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Order.class)
                                .setFetchMode("items", FetchMode.JOIN)
                                .setFetchMode("discountEntries", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.list();
```

- Cannot fetch multiple bags

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Order.class)
                                .createAlias("items", "items", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN)
                                .setFetchMode("items", FetchMode.JOIN)
                                .createAlias("discountEntries", "discountEntries", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN)
                                .setFetchMode("discountEntries", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.list();
```

- Returns an empty list

EDIT: Added another ManyToMany association as that seems to be part of the problem.

Comment: I've managed to achieve this with setFetchMode("items", FetchMode.JOIN) by changing the Lists to Sets (this gets rids of the "multiple bags" problem). This causes outer joins, however, and a cartesian join. I'm looking for a way to do this with subselects ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the collection with the `LAZY` setting and :

```
List list = criteria.list();
Hibernate.initialize(list);
```

This will initialize it immediately, only for this case.

Comment: To add to your answer - this will result in an outer join unless you use @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) on the association in your entity.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try: `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`? what was the result?

Comment: It loads the items correctly - eagerly, but I only want to do this for one Criteria, not all the time. Thus I need some way to load it eagerly on the Criteria.